# SQL Select only Data thats no SINGLE-duplicate

Tags: sql, select

I hope u can help me out on more time ;-)
Dont know if its possible but i have this table called `GAMES`:

```
NAME     MEMBERS
soccer   tina
soccer   tina
soccer   dirk
soccer   dirk
skate    john
skate    john
```

as you can see there are double entries (thats ok and i need it this way).
i want to output the NAME_COLUMN and it works with:

```
SELECT name 
FROM   games
```

--> output "Soccer,Skate"

now i need only names from columns where the double entries are not equal (like in skate) but wanted names (soccer) have equals too (but not only equals). is there someting working like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM   games 
WHERE  Count(DISTINCT members > 1)
```

cos when i count with DISTINCT the members i get right results (2 for soccer and 1 for skate)

or may something like:

```
SELECT name 
FROM   games 
WHERE  "not all entries same"
```

i want as result only "Soccer"

I hope u understand ;-) 
*its just a dummy table to understand for my real solution in desktop programming

Comment: GROUP BY and HAVING seems to be the keywords you're after.

Comment: you have said below, 'i have more columns with not equal entries', can you please mention what all columns you have except name and members, try adding your data in fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e08aa/2

Comment: no i mean not more columns sorry i mean more entries. ur queries work and show "soccer" - as i wanted BUT it has to show soccer,bowl,...and some others. thats what i mean. there are more entries that the output schould have - but it has only soccer!?

Answer (score 6):

`Group by` the `Name` and use `having` to count the group members

```
Select NAME 
from GAMES 
group by NAME
having count(DISTINCT MEMBERS) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the following statement is wrong in sql;
`where count(DISTINCT MEMBERS > 1)`.

You should rather use the **HAVING** statement, without any **WHERE**;

```
Select   NAME 
from     GAMES 
group by NAME
having count(DISTINCT (MEMBERS) > 1)
```

Comment: both where working: "having count(DISTINCT (MEMBERS) > 1)" AND "having count(DISTINCT MEMBERS) > 1" but both display only 1 columns(1 different) i have more columns with not equal entries. both query show another columns but only one...i need output of all??

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
Select NAME 
from GAMES 
group by NAME
having count(DISTINCT MEMBERS) > 1
```

Comment: both where working: "having count(DISTINCT (MEMBERS) > 1)" AND "having count(DISTINCT MEMBERS) > 1" but both display only 1 columns(1 different) i have more columns with not equal entries. both query show another columns but only one...i need output of all??